# Sql Server query for tree path of one item

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, tree, common-table-expression

I need a SQL query giving me the complete tree path of one item. The tables Looks like this and there is a 1:n relation between MyItem_MyItemId and MyItemMapping_MyItemId.

Table MyItem:

```
MyItem_MyItemId | MyItem_Title 
1 | Desktop
2 | Workspace
3 | Folder1
4 | Folder2
5 | Folder3
6 | Folder4
...
```

Table MyItemMapping:

```
MyItemMapping_MyItemId | MyItemMapping_MyItemParentId
4 | 3
3 | 2
2 | 1
1 | NULL
5 | 2
6 | 2
...
```

Now I Need a query the brings the path for the Folder2 like "Desktop\Workspace\Folder1\Folder2.

I tried it with a Recursive Query (see below) but SQL Server Needs about 10 seconds to resolve it. I have only 5000 records in database. I could figure out that with this query, the path is calculated for all 5000 records but I Need it only of one item. Can anybody help me?

```
WITH 
MyTable as
(
 select MyItem_MyItemId, MyItem_Title, MyItemMapping_MyItemParentId 
 from MyItem inner join MyItemMapping on MyItem_MyItemId = MyItemMapping_MyItemId
),
RecursiveTable AS 
(
  select t.MyItem_MyItemId, t.MyItem_Title, t.MyItemMapping_MyItemParentId
  from MyTable as t
  Where MyItemMapping_MyItemParentId is null 
  union all
  select  t.MyItem_MyItemId,  CAST(RecursiveTable.MyItem_Title + '\' + t.MyItem_Title AS NVARCHAR(max)), t.MyItemMapping_MyItemParentId
  from MyTable as t
  JOIN RecursiveTable ON RecursiveTable.MyItem_MyItemId = t.MyItemMapping_MyItemParentId
)   
select MyItem_Title from RecursiveTable where MyItem_MyItemid = 4
```

Thank you vey much.

Best regards.
Marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move in the opposite direction. After selected is necessary items, use pattern with [FOR XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx) clause for creating a list of backslash delimited valid values.

```
DECLARE @MyItemMapping_MyItemId int = 4
;WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT MyItemMapping_MyItemId, MyItemMapping_MyItemParentId, 1 AS rn
  FROM MyItemMapping
  Where MyItemMapping_MyItemId = @MyItemMapping_MyItemId 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT m.MyItemMapping_MyItemId, m.MyItemMapping_MyItemParentId, rn + 1
  FROM MyItemMapping m JOIN cte c ON c.MyItemMapping_MyItemParentId = m.MyItemMapping_MyItemId
  )
  SELECT STUFF((SELECT '/' + m.MyItem_Title                   
                FROM cte c JOIN MyItem m                 
                  ON c.MyItemMapping_MyItemId = m.MyItem_MyItemId
                ORDER BY c.rn DESC                    
                FOR XML PATH, TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') AS pathFolder
```

pathFolder

Result:

```
PathFolder

Desktop/Workspace/Folder1/Folder2
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b008e/4)

Comment: The result of this is "Folder2/Folder1/Workspace/Desktop". Is there an easy way to Change it to "Desktop/Workspace/Folder1/Folder2"?

Comment: @user1797911 I'm sorry but I don't quite understand why your result "Folder2/Folder1/Workspace/Desktop"?!?! In my example on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b008e/2) works perfect. Please check it again.

Comment: In SQLFiddle it's ok but in SQL Management Studio it's the other way round.

Comment: Possible need add ORDER BY clause. I update answer..Try again

Comment: An order by is not possible because the id's are not ordered. I use uniqueidentifiers as id's as well, so an order by wouldn't be a possibility either. Any other ideas?

Comment: Ok.Let's create the consistently increased column. Hence you can sort your data;) Answer updated..Try again

Comment: Thanx Alexander thats great.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the query:

```
declare @MyItem as table (MyItem_MyItemId INT, MyItem_Title nvarchar(50))

insert into @MyItem values 
(1, 'Desktop'),
(2, 'Workspace'),
(3, 'Folder1'),
(4, 'Folder2')

declare @MyItemMapping as table (MyItemMapping_MyItemId INT, MyItemMapping_MyItemParentId int)

insert into @MyItemMapping values
(4, 3),
(3, 2),
(2, 1),
(1, NULL)

select * From @MyItem
select * From @MyItemMapping

;WITH parent AS
(
    SELECT MyItemMapping_MyItemId, MyItemMapping_MyItemParentId, CAST( b.MyItem_Title as nvarchar(max))MyItem_Title
    from @MyItemMapping a INNER JOIN @MyItem b on a.MyItemMapping_MyItemId=b.MyItem_MyItemId
    WHERE MyItemMapping_MyItemParentId is NULL

    UNION ALL 
    SELECT t.MyItemMapping_MyItemId, t.MyItemMapping_MyItemParentId ,CAST( parent.MyItem_Title+'/'+ b.MyItem_Title as nvarchar(max))MyItem_Title
    FROM parent INNER JOIN @MyItemMapping t ON parent.MyItemMapping_MyItemId =  t.MyItemMapping_MyItemParentId
        INNER JOIN @MyItem b on t.MyItemMapping_MyItemId=b.MyItem_MyItemId
)

SELECT MyItem_Title FROM  parent where MyItemMapping_MyItemId=(select MAX(MyItem_MyItemId) from @MyItem)
```

OR

```
declare @output varchar(max)
;WITH parent AS
(
    SELECT MyItemMapping_MyItemId, MyItemMapping_MyItemParentId
    from @MyItemMapping
    WHERE MyItemMapping_MyItemParentId is NULL

    UNION ALL 
    SELECT t.MyItemMapping_MyItemId, t.MyItemMapping_MyItemParentId 
    FROM parent INNER JOIN @MyItemMapping t ON parent.MyItemMapping_MyItemId =  t.MyItemMapping_MyItemParentId
)

SELECT @output = COALESCE(@output + '/', '')+ (select MyItem_Title from @MyItem where MyItem_MyItemId=MyItemMapping_MyItemId) 
FROM  parent where MyItemMapping_MyItemId <= 4 group by MyItemMapping_MyItemId order by MyItemMapping_MyItemId

select @output
```

Comment: This is the same result like I post in the question. If there are 5000 entries in the tables, it Needs more than 10 seconds as well. I need the path only from one item. With your query the recursion will be done for all items as well. Thank you very much, but this is unfortunately not the solution. Do you have an other idea?

Comment: oh... I see... I have added one more query... plz check the new way.

Comment: I added two more example values in table description above. As soon as you do it with this tables below, it will not give my expected result: insert into MyItem values 
(1, 'Desktop'),
(2, 'Workspace'),
(3, 'Folder1'),
(4, 'Folder2'),
(5, 'Folder3'),
(6, 'Folder4')

declare MyItemMapping as table (MyItemMapping_MyItemId INT, MyItemMapping_MyItemParentId int)

insert into MyItemMapping values
(4, 3),
(3, 2),
(2, 1),
(1, NULL),
(5, 2),
(6, 2) . For example id 5 and 6  should not apppear in the result. I expect only  "Desktop\Workspace\Folder1\Folder2. Any other idea?