# How to generate (join) table field using existing string field as source?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to generate (join) a new field by combining existing fields as source ?

I have a table like this:

```
id | title | parent_id | path
1  | a     | 0         | 1
2  | b     | 1         | 1/2
3  | c     | 1         | 1/3
4  | d     | 3         | 1/3/4
```

I want to use the "path" field's string (numbers) as a kind of index and generate (join) a new field using titles insead ids like:

```
id | title | parent_id | path | title_path
1  | a     | 0         | 1    | a
2  | b     | 1         | 1/2  | a/b
3  | c     | 1         | 1/3  | a/c
4  | d     | 3         | 1/3/4| a/c/d
```

Is this possible using sql on itself or should I use php for this?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18106947/cte-recursion-to-get-tree-hierarchy/18111876 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585155/sql-server-query-for-tree-path-of-one-item

Comment: Now you see why delimited lists of pretty much anything is a bad idea in a database. Proper database design would have made this quite easy

Comment: @Skeletor . . . It is probably easier to use PHP.  In MySQL 8+, you can use a recursive CTE if need be.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you are right. Will modify it with php, looks best way for me.